# Is it possible to redeploy without deleting the database?

Tags: jhipster

During the deployment, I see that if I do not delete the database it does not work.
Is it possible to redeploy without deleting the database?
I use postgres as a database server.

Comment: It should work, what error do you see? Is it due to liquibase checksums ?

Comment: I think if I make database changes, it creates problems for me during the deployment. Can help me get the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add logs showing the error message or you won't get any help. Make sure you have read the "Database updates" section of the doc : https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates

Comment: ok i'll see the link for more understanding